# WHERE clause great than zero still showing zero when using CASE functions

Tags: sql, null, pivot, where-clause, having-clause

I am trying the WHERE clause to filter out other data I dont want.

```
SELECT `post_id`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `meta_key` = 'vlaue_1' THEN `meta_value` ELSE NULL END) as 'Customer',
       MAX(CASE WHEN `meta_key` = 'value_2' THEN `meta_value` ELSE NULL  END) as 'DeliveryDate',
        MAX(CASE WHEN `meta_key` = 'value_3' THEN `meta_value` ELSE NULL  END) as 'DeliveryTime',
         MAX(CASE WHEN `meta_key` = 'vlaue_4' THEN `meta_value` ELSE NULL  END) as 'DeliveryType'
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE 'Customer' > 0
GROUP BY `post_id`  
ORDER BY `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` ASC
```

The above is returning the error 'Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value'. Yes I have looked this up a number of places including stackoverflow and understand its meaning except not in this instance.

OK so I thought I wouldnt use 'customer' at all. No problem. I will tell it to search for when the 'Customer'is not null using WHERE 'Customer' IS NOT NULL. That gives me this image where it displays everything null AND the records I am seeking.
[pic of db when not null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnbPL.png)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` logic belongs in a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    post_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'vlaue_1' THEN meta_value END) AS Customer,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_2' THEN meta_value END) AS DeliveryDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_3' THEN meta_value END) AS DeliveryTime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_4' THEN meta_value END) AS DeliveryType
FROM wp_postmeta 
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING Customer > 0
ORDER BY post_id;
```

Note that your current `WHERE` clause might technically be valid MySQL:

```
WHERE 'Customer' > 0
```

However, this checks whether the string literal `'Customer'` is greater than the value 0.  It does *not* actually check the value of the customer case expression, which is not even available until after group by happens.

Comment: Thanks. Since it is creating the 'Customer' what is the solution to pulling the data after it groups them?

Comment: Using my answer?  Not sure what else I can say here...

Comment: Does seem to be working so I guess its not an issue that it is only checking the string before pulling in everything? It does seem to prevent being able to order by. Would that make sense? Thanks for the continuing help

Comment: In your answer, the `having` should be `where`.

Comment: WHERE was the issue and can not be used with function clauses. The question now is why with the HERE, why does the ORDER BY clause have no effect