# sql clauses using HAVING truncated value error for part of the string

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-like, having-clause

I am getting an integer value error but don't understand why.

> Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '%accepted%';
>
> Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '%pending%' .

It does not have the error for processing. It doesnt matter what is in "1st position" doesnt have the error.

Could someone please help?

```
SELECT a.`post_id`, b.`name`,
       MAX(case when meta_key = 'value' THEN `meta_value` ELSE NULL END) as  'Email',
FROM table_1 a

INNER JOIN table_2 b
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.post_id, b.payment_ids)
GROUP BY a.post_id
HAVING OrderStatus LIKE '%processing%' OR '%pending%' OR '%accepted%' AND DeliveryDate >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND DeliveryType = 'pickup'
```

Comment: You can’t just OR values. You need to have complete statements, so `OrderStatus like ... OR OrderStatus like ...`

Comment: Ah thank you very much for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.`post_id`, b.`name`,
       MAX(case when meta_key = 'value' THEN `meta_value` ELSE NULL END) as  'Email',
FROM table_1 a

INNER JOIN table_2 b
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.post_id, b.payment_ids)
GROUP BY a.post_id
HAVING OrderStatus LIKE '%processing%' OR OrderStatus LIKE '%pending%' OR OrderStatus LIKE '%accepted%' AND DeliveryDate >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND DeliveryType = 'pickup'
```

Answer (score 1):

> `OrderStatus LIKE '%processing%' OR '%pending%' OR '%accepted%'`

This does not do what you think. MySQL understands it as:

```
(OrderStatus LIKE '%processing%')
OR ('%pending%')
OR ('%accepted%')
```

So it tries to evaluate the strings in boolean context, which produces the warning that you are getting.

You need to repeat the `like` expression for each matched string:

```
(
    OrderStatus LIKE '%processing%' 
    OR OrderStatus LIKE '%pending%' 
    OR OrderStatus LIKE '%accepted%'
)
```

Or you can use a regexp:

```
OrderStatus RLIKE 'processing|pending|accepted'
```

Note that these conditions should belong to the `where` clause rather than the `having` clause, since they relate to non-aggregated columns. I would phrase the query as:

```
select
    t1.post_id,
    t2.name,
    -- no need for an "else" branch here
    max(case when meta_key = 'value' then meta_value end) as email 
from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2 on find_in_set(t1.post_id, t2.payment_ids)
where
-- filtering in the "where" clause
    OrderStatus rlike 'processing|pending|accepted'    -- regex
    and DeliveryDate >= current_date - interval 7 day  -- no need for "datesub()"
    and DeliveryType = 'pickup'
group by 
-- all non-aggregated column in the `group by` clause    
    t1.post_id, 
    t2.name
```

Note that you should prefix *all* columns in the query with the table they belong to, to make the code unambiguous and self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks I was told I could not use the WHERE clause and when I had tried it created errors. Yes I did have it in the proper place. It would just provide an empty result set

Comment: In continuing to play it provides a Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect date value: 'DeliveryDate' while posting an empty results set. Previously I used to have the WHERE clause but was corrected on this post - [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432930/where-clause-great-than-zero-still-showing-zero-when-using-case-functions/63432952#63432952 [link]

Comment: @Tim: this does not come from the query I gave you. But probably, you have single quotes around column name `DeliveryDate` that should not be there.

Comment: Correct. If I have no quotes I get an error #1054 - Unknown column 'DeliveryType' in 'where clause'

Comment: Correct. If I have no quotes I get an error #1054 - Unknown column 'DeliveryType' in 'where clause' – Tim